# How can I disable Spring AOP transaction support?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a simple Spring Boot app that does its own JDBC stuff including transaction management. How can I disable the Spring TransactionInterceptor stuff wrapping calls to my services? Its not causing any trouble but I don't need it and would like slightly better performance and shorter stack traces:

```
at icu.intervals.service.ActivityRepo.listActivitiesForNav(ActivityRepo.java:342) [main/:na]
at icu.intervals.service.ActivityRepo$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4c15c12d.invoke(<generated>) [main/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746) [spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) [spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) [spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) [spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at icu.intervals.service.ActivityRepo$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2fc083de.listActivitiesForNav(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
at icu.intervals.web.ApiController.listActivities(ApiController.java:336) ~[main/:na]
```

Comment: What annotations did you use in your ActivityRepo class?

Comment: None. I have tried @Transactional with various settings but none of them seem to get rid of the proxying.

Comment: If you have no annotations at all, Spring wouldn't recognize it as bean. Could you post the code of that class?

Comment: Sorry I thought you meant @ Transactional. It has @ Repository only.

Comment: Maybe to try something like:
spring.aop.proxy-target-class=false

Comment: I tried that, also spring.aop.auto=false. No luck.

Comment: `@Repository` enables `PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor` by default, so it's not just the `TransactionInterceptor`. And somehow in your config it also states that your `ActivityRepo` is eligible to also wrap invocations into transaction aspect. It might be stated in many places and in many ways, without debugging - hard to tell exactly where.

Comment: I was hoping for a just spring.xxx=false in application.properties. Oh well.